# Android - Store Image Manually and Display Image From Preloaded Database

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite

May I know how to store an image manually into a database without using codes/programming? How do I go about doing that? How do I even save it as a BLOB type? Or do I save the image URL(from local desktop location and not from the internet) to the database? And after which, how do I go about displaying the image from the preloaded database and display it in the image view?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find alternatives to settle down with. Which is to save the image file name into the database and store the images in the application's asset folder after which display the image by the path name in webview.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to store images on your device, am i wright? As for me the best practice is to save them on SD card and remember the path in DB.

For easy saving you can use bitmap map method compress which receives outputstream to sd card path as a parameter

Comment: I want to save the images in a preloaded database, meaning, I would like to display images that are stored in the database when the user clicks into a detailed info of a listview. Not to save them when the app is running.